# Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio - cannot create DB engine

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I just installed Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 17.2. I am trying to create a DB Engine on my local computer. My goal is to have a local demo database which I can create and modify tables.

I followed [basic articles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/lesson-1-connecting-to-the-database-engine) in the web saying that I only need to write my computer name as a server name and use windows authentication.

I am constantly getting this error:

> TITLE: Connect to Server
>
> Cannot connect to f.
>
> ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 53)
>
> The network path was not found

So to repeat again - my goal is only to be able to create database with random data. I need it for demo purposes.

Comment: Connecting to a database engine, does not create it. You need to install a product called Microsoft SQL Server [look here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/install-windows/install-sql-server) for more information. If you have any issues a recommend asking on [dba.stackexchange.com](dba.stackexchange.com) which is better suited for this.

Comment: Note that SSMS is just a client tool that can manage and connect to existing SQL Server instances. The SQL Server server software (database engine) is installed separately.

Comment: You obviously only installed SSMS - the **GUI** management tool - that is ***NOT*** a database that you can connect to! You need to install an actual **SQL Server database** version, too!

Comment: Thanks, folks.. This was the case. Amateur mistake.